# Piecewise $C_1$ and piecewise continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I would appreciate if the following questions could be clarified with your help.

1. If a function is piecewise $C_1$, does this imply that it's also piecewise continuous?
2. If a function is piecewise continuous, does this imply that it's also piecewise $C_1$?
3. Is the sawtooth function continuous? If so, it has sharp "bumps", why is it still considered continuous on its domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any differentiable function is continuous. So 1 is clearly "yes". 2 is "no", there are lots of continuous functions which are not even differentiable at *any point*, the most famous examples of which are due to Weierstrass. For 3, I might recommend reviewing the definition of continuity; intuitively, a sawtooth wave can be drawn without picking one's pencil up off the paper. It is not *differentiable* at the corners, though.